# PyTorch LinearLayer+BatchNorm1d with a 3D input

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization

I would like to apply a `BatchNorm1d` after a `Linear`. My input is a 3D multivariate time series of shape [batch_size, n_variables, timesteps]. The `Linear` performs the linear transformation on the third dimension so that the new shape is [batch_size, n_variables, LinearLayer_out_features]. My problem occurs with the `BatchNorm1d`, I would like to apply it on the third dimension but, for a 3D input, `BatchNorm1d` operation is done over the second dimension (even for a 3D tensor). Do you have any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not transpose the input to BatchNorm1d and then transpose it back?

```
m=Linear(.....)
m=torch.transpose(BatchNorm1D(torch.transpose(m,1,2)),1,2)
```

This doesn't create a copy of your tensor.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html